# Applying code to index only

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code which adds/removes a 'white' or 'black' class to my #anim-nav

I want this code to only work on my index page (i want .black applied all th time on the other pages) This code is in a separate .js page brought in through the header (thus on all the pages)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
  $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
  } else {
  $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
 }
});
```

Comment: So to make it clear, you want add/remove `.black` jquery for all the pages but do not want add/remove `.white` jquery for except the index page.

Comment: Sort of the opposite. I just want the 'white' query to work on the homepage

Answer (score 0):

Simple use something like that..........

```php
    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
    // Default homepage
      $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
      $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-
      fill').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
      } else {
      $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-
      fill').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
     }
    });

    }
```

Comment: There's only two tpes of pages in this. A home and single.php pages

Comment: Yes cause it's over an image on the index page, and not on any of the others

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put a `hidden` input type in the index page (should not be in header but the separate index page)

```
<input type="hidden" name="is_index" value="1" id="is_index">
```

then get its value in jquery like this and use it into the condition:

```
var is_index = '';
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
 is_index = $('#is_index').val();
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75 && is_index == 1) {
  $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
  } else {
  $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
 }
});
```

Comment: SO this will work since the target is in the header (my navigation bar)

Comment: Doesn't seem to change for the interior pages

Comment: You should put the jquery code in general file which is included in all the pages (something like header file) and the input type hidden should be put in the home page code only.

Comment: So just script it in the head on header should work then

Answer (score 0):

You can validate via the `href`

First you get the location

```
window.location.href
```

This will return a string that you can check if it includes `index` usign the `includes()`function

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75  && !window.location.href.includes('index')) {
  $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
  } else {
  $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It can not be sure that the URL will have `index` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an input element or add a css class to any index page element or check any unique class exist on index page then in js code you can check that if its exist then only code will run

For example we add a class **homeClass** on a index page html element then in js you can check like below example.

**JS CODE EXAMPLE**

```
if($(".homeClass").length) {
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75) {
  $('#anim-nav').addClass('bg-fill').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
  } else {
  $('#anim-nav').removeClass('bg-fill').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
 }
}
});
```